# Significado de «Pase revista»

Tags: significado, modismos

Estoy leyendo un libro con la siguiente frase:

> Pase revista a la situación en el contexto de su círculo de influencia.

Creo que entiendo el sentido general de la frase: Que me pide que considere el contexto de mi círculo de influencia.

Pero no entiendo el sentido exacto de «Pase revista».  Entiendo que «Pase» es la forma imperativa de la segunda persona del verbo «pasar».  Pero no estoy familiarizado con la palabra «revista» en ese contexto.

¿Cuál es el significado de «Pase revista», literalmente, y si se aplica, figuradamente?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Revista](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=CswXznQuGDXX258dpyuk) en este contexto de "pasar revista" tiene el significado de

> **Inspección** que un jefe hace de las personas o cosas sometidas a su autoridad o a su cuidado

Es un término militar para referirse a la verificación de las tropas en un acto o ceremonia militar (los soldados están en fila y la figura con autoridad comprueba que los uniformes estén limpios, que los soldados sepan mantener la formación o pose adecuada, etc.).

El modismo transciende el ámbito militar (pasar revista a las tropas) y puede ser entendido a modo general como una comprobación, revisión o examen minucioso de algo, posiblemente incluyendo el *visto bueno* final del revisor.

Comment: Por revista como mencionan en la respuesta anterior es un termino militar, haciendo alusión a revisar, verificar .